# Custom serialize and parse methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, serialization, recursion

I have developed this `class Directory` that some what emulates a directory using hashes. I have difficulties figuring out how to do the `serialize` and `parse` methods. The returned `string` from the `serialize` method should look something like this:

```
2:README:19:string:Hello world!spec.rb:20:string:describe RBFS1:rbfs:4:0:0:
```

Now to explain what exactly this means. This is the master directory and the `2` upfront means the number of files, than we have the file name `README` and after that the length of the contents of the file `19`, represented with a string that I get from the `parse` method of the other class in the module. And after that the second file, also notice that the two files are not separated by `:`, we don't need it here since when know the string length. So in a little better look:

`<file count><file1_data><file2_data>1:rbfs:4:0:0:`, here `<file1_data>`, encompasses the name, length and contents part.

Now the `1:rbfs:4:0:0:` means we have one sub-directory with name `rbfs`, `4` representing the length of it's contents as a string and `0:0:` representing that it's empty, no file and no sub-directories. Here is another example:

`0:1:directory1:40:0:1:directory2:22:1:README:9:number:420:` which is equivalent to:

```
.
`-- directory1
    `-- directory2
        `-- README
```

I have no problem with the files part,and i know how to get the number of directories and their names, but the other part I have no idea what to do. I know that `recursion` is the best answer, but I have no clue what should the bottom of that recursion be and how to implement it. Also solving this will help greatly in figuring out how to do the `parse` method by reverse engineering it.

The code is below:

```
module RBFS
class File
  ... # here I have working `serialize` and `parse` methods for `File`
end

class Directory
attr_accessor :content
def initialize
  @content = {}
end

def add_file (name,file)
  @content[name]=file
end

def add_directory(name, subdirectory = nil)
  if subdirectory
    @content[name] = subdirectory
  else
    @content[name] = RBFS::Directory.new
  end
end

def serialize
  ...?
end

def self.parse (string)
  ...?
end
end

end
```

---

PS: I check the kind of values in the hash with the `is_a?` method.

Another example for @Jordan:

```
2:file1:17:string:Test test?file2:10:number:4322:direc1:34:0:1:dir2:22:1:README:9:number:420:direc2::1:README2:9:number:33:0
```

...should be this structure (if I've formulated it right):

```
. ->file1,file2
`-- direc1,.....................................direc2 -> README2
    `-- dir2(subdirectory of direc1) -> README
```

`direc1` contains only a directory and no files, while `direc2` contains only a file.
You can see that the master directory doesn't specify it's string length while all others do.

Comment: Can you give an example of the serialization of a slightly more complex directory structure, e.g. multiple non-empty sibling directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's work through this iteratively, starting with your example:

```
str = "2:README:19:string:Hello world!spec.rb:20:string:describe RBFS1:rbfs:4:0:0:"
entries = {} # No entries yet!
```

The very first thing we need to know is how many files there are, and we know we know that's the number before the first `:`:

```
num_entries, rest = str.split(':', 2)
num_entries = Integer(num_entries)
# num_entries is now 2
# rest is now "README:19:string:Hello world!spec.rb:20:string:describe RBFS1:rbfs:4:0:0:"
```

The second argument to `split` says "I only want 2 pieces," so it stops splitting after the first `:`.) We use `Integer(n)` instead of `n.to_i` because it's stricter. (`to_i` will convert `"10xyz"` to `10`; `Integer` will raise an error, which is what we want here.)

Now we know we have two files. We don't know anything else yet, but what's left of our string is this:

```
README:19:string:Hello world!spec.rb:20:string:describe RBFS1:rbfs:4:0:0:
```

The next thing we can get is the name and length of the first file.

```
name, len, rest = rest.split(':', 3)
len = Integer(len.to_i)
# name = "README"
# len  = 19
# rest = "string:Hello world!spec.rb:20:string:describe RBFS1:rbfs:4:0:0:"
```

Cool, now we have the name and length of the first file, so we can get its content:

```
content = rest.slice!(0, len)
# content = "string:Hello world!"
# rest = "spec.rb:20:string:describe RBFS1:rbfs:4:0:0:"
entries[name] = content
# entries = { "README" => "string:Hello world!" }
```

We used `rest.slice!` which modifies removes `len` characters from the front of the string and returns them, so `content` is just what we want (`string:Hello world!`) and `rest` is everything that was after it. Then we added it to `entries` Hash. One file down, one to go!

For the second file, we do the exact same thing:

```
name, len, rest = rest.split(':', 3)
len = Integer(len)
# name = "spec.rb"
# len = 20
# rest = "string:describe RBFS1:rbfs:4:0:0:"

content = rest.slice!(0, len)
# content = "string:describe RBFS"
# rest  = "1:rbfs:4:0:0:"
entries[name] = content
# entries = { "README" => "string:Hello world!",
#             "spec.rb" => "string:describe RBFS" }
```

Since we do the exact same thing twice, obviously we should do this in a loop! But before we write that, we need to get organized. So far we have two discrete steps: First, get the number of files. Second, get those files' contents. We also know we'll need to get the number of directories and the directories. We'll take a guess at how this'll look:

```
def parse(serialized)
  files, rest = parse_files(serialized)
  # `files` will be a Hash of file names and their contents and `rest` will be
  # the part of the string we haven't serialized yet
  directories, rest = parse_directories(rest)
  # `directories` will be a Hash of directory names and their contents

  files.merge(directories)
end

def parse_files(serialized)
  # Get the number of files from the beginning of the string
  num_entries, rest = str.split(':', 2)
  num_entries = Integer(num_entries)
  entries = {}

  # `rest` now starts with the first file (e.g. "README:19:...")
  num_entries.times do
    name, len, rest = rest.split(':', 3) # get the file name and length
    len = Integer(len)

    content = rest.slice!(0, len) # get the file contents from the beginning of the string
    entries[name] = content # add it to the hash
  end

  [ entries, rest ]
end

def parse_directories(serialized)
  # TBD...
end
```

That `parse_files` method is a bit long for my taste, though, so how about we split it up?

```
def parse_files(serialized)
  # Get the number of files from the beginning of the string
  num_entries, rest = str.split(':', 2)
  num_entries = Integer(num_entries)
  entries = {}

  # `rest` now starts with the first file (e.g. "README:19:...")
  num_entries.times do
    name, content, rest = parse_file(rest)
    entries[name] = content # add it to the hash
  end

  [ entries, rest ]
end

def parse_file(serialized)
  name, len, rest = serialized.split(':', 3) # get the name and length of the file
  len = Integer(len)

  content = rest.slice!(0, len) # use the length to get its contents
  [ name, content, rest ]
end
```

Clean!

Now, I'm going to give you a big spoiler: Since the serialization format is reasonably well-designed, we don't actually need a `parse_directories` method, because it would do exactly the same thing as `parse_files`. The *only* difference is that after this line:

```
name, content, rest = parse_file(rest)
```

...we want to do something different if we're parsing directories instead of files. In particular, we want to call `parse(content)`, which will do all of this over again on the directory's contents. Since it's pulling double-duty now, we should probably change it's name to something more general like `parse_entries`, and we also need to give it another argument to tell it when to do that recursion.

Rather than post more code here, I've posted my "finished" product [over in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jrunning/56b76e7580bbe2e9a07b).

Now, I know that doesn't help you with the `serialize` part, but hopefully it'll help get you started. `serialize` is the easier part because there are plenty of questions and answers on SO about recursively iterating over a Hash.

Comment: Thank, you are awesome, quick question though what does this exactly do `[ entries, rest ]` and `[ name, content, rest ]`

Comment: Those are just arrays. The real trick is Ruby's destructuring assignment: When you do `var1, var2 = some_array`, it will assign the first item in `some_array` to `var1` and the second to `var2`. If instead of `some_array` you have a method that returns an array, like `parse_entries`, it does the same thing. In other words, it's a way to return multiple values from a method. You should do this sparingly—mostly because it's non-obvious and hard to document—but in some situations it can be very useful.